# adobe xd prototype design

Tags: user-interface, ui-design, adobe-xd

I am beginner level user for adobe xd. I have to do prototype using adobe xd. can i use adobe xd for these type of requirement. I have basic idea bout layout design and navigation. please check the attached image[image]

in this screen user can add row to grid. after user can enter product name and amount and save. Total amount should update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the design of it, in XD. And maybe animate it.
But you can't make it function that way

Answer (score 0):

Adobe XD is a prototyping tool, it has been designed for producing the designs of websites and app before passing it to a developer that will "manually" build the HTML/CSS/JS out of it.

Update: But, You can try ["animaapp"](https://www.animaapp.com/xd) for getting your design code (HTML, CSS).